# How to disable specific dates in react-native-datetime-picker?

Tags: react-native, datetimepicker

Dates can be disabled in react-day-picker, but i could not find a way to disable specific dates in react-native-datetime-picker. It is possible to disable a range of dates but not a specific date.
Is it possible to disable certain dates in the react-native-datetime-picker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use react-native-date-picker for this. but there is library available for this . it is `react-native-calendars` . Following snippet will give you the idea how to do it.

```
const vacation = {key:'vacation', color: 'red', selectedDotColor: 'blue'};
const massage = {key:'massage', color: 'blue', selectedDotColor: 'blue'};
const workout = {key:'workout', color: 'green'};

<Calendar
  markedDates={{
    '2017-10-25': {dots: [vacation, massage, workout], selected: true, selectedColor: 'red'},
    '2017-10-26': {dots: [massage, workout], disabled: true}
  }}
  markingType={'multi-dot'}
/>
```

For more info [react-native-calendars](https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars)